# Resize SVG using percentage

Tags: html, svg, width

How do I resize an `SVG` relative to its "native" (`viewBox`?) size?

When I use percentage on an `IMG` inside a table it scales to the right size, but the table does not register the width scaling and stays as if its width is still at `100%`.

Here is an example. The first is the svg at `100%`, the second shows `50%` and the border around the table makes the non-scaling visible. The third uses a width in `px` and scales fine.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="border: 1px solid;"><img src="http://www.inkscape.org/design/images/inkscape-logo.svg" width="100%"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="border: 1px solid;"><img src="http://www.inkscape.org/design/images/inkscape-logo.svg" width="50%"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="border: 1px solid;"><img src="http://www.inkscape.org/design/images/inkscape-logo.svg" width="50px"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is also a http://jsfiddle.net/kUQrV/.

Comment: Put the style on the `<img>` element and you'll see it's scaling fine.

Comment: Thank your for the comment. I see your point, but that would still leave the table too wide. I just found a couple of related posts concerning `IMG` in general. One way to achieve the wanted result is to add `onload="this.width*=.5"` on the `IMG`. I guess it does not work without javascript (enabled) then.